# Is it possible to reuse schema context in libxml2 when validating multiple xml buffers or files?

Tags: xml, schema, libxml2

learning to use the libxml2 library, and I'm trying to develop code that uses the same schema file to validate either multiple buffers of xml data or multiple files of xml data. But it looks like I have to get a new schema parse context, parse the schema file into it, and then get a new schema context each time before using an xml reader to read the buffer or file. If I don't it does a segfault. Below is an example code (linux based compile). ctxt_allocated is a global initialized to FALSE, so it does the xmlSchemaNewParserCtxt(), xmlSchemaParse() and xmlSchemaNewValidCtxt() calls once to produce the valid_ctxt (another global) once and use over and over. This code fails with the segfault.
Reason to want this: Eventually I could have bunches of schemas to apply to the data, with lots of either xml buffers or xml files to validate, and I would like to do it as efficiently as possible (ie, if its possible to only do it once, do it once), rather than creating/destroying the schema contexts over and over. I'ved tried saving the parser ctxt, the parsed schema, and the schema ctxt (and all possible combos) without success, and the documentation is sparse - I can't find something like "reinitialize context".

```
    // This first section is what I'd like to only do ONCE to get valid_cxt
    // but it fails no matter which part I save: the parser context, the parsed schema
    // or the schema context
    if (!ctxt_allocated) {
        if (schema_parser_ctxt = xmlSchemaNewParserCtxt(schemaFilePath)))
        {
            schema = xmlSchemaParse(schema_parser_ctxt);
            xmlSchemaFreeParserCtxt(schema_parser_ctxt);
            if (schema) {
                valid_ctxt = xmlSchemaNewValidCtxt(schema);
                ctx_allocated = true;
            }
        }
    }
    xmlTextReaderPtr reader = NULL;
    reader = xmlReaderForMemory(xmlBuf, strlen(xmlBuf), NULL, NULL, XML_PARSE_HUGE | XML_PARSE_NONET);

    if (reader != NULL) {
        if (valid_ctxt) {
            xmlTextReaderSchemaValidateCtxt(reader, valid_ctxt, 0);
            xmlSchemaSetValidStructuredErrors(valid_ctxt, schemaParseErrorHandler, &has_schema_errors);
        }

        ret = xmlTextReaderRead(reader);
        while (ret == 1 && !has_schema_errors) {
            ret = xmlTextReaderRead(reader);
        }

        if (ret != 0) {
            xmlErrorPtr err = xmlGetLastError();
           printf("Failed to parse. Error %d: %s\n", err->code, err->message);
        }
    }
    else {
        xmlErrorPtr err = xmlGetLastError();
        printf("Failed to get reader!. Error %d: %s\n", err->code, err->message);
    }
```

Tried above code. Expecting a way to reuse created schema context over and over.

Comment: You could try to use another API to parse/validate the document instead of `xmlTextReader` which is rather inefficient anyway. I'd suggest `xmlReadMemory` and `xmlSchemaValidateDoc`. If this doesn't work, simply recreate the validation context each time. It's not very expensive.